# Access last databound ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I'm working on a WP7 app where I use a pre-populated SQLCE database. Therefore I use a lot of databound controls. Right now I'm a bit in trouble.
To keep it short: I need to access the last ListBoxItem (not the business object) of a databound ListBox and change some Properties like the Margin of that last Item.
I was not able to get this Item by using the methods of the VisualTreeHelper class nor by using something like

```
(myListBox.Items.Last() as ListBoxItem).Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

because myListBox.Items seems to be null (!?)

There is some black magic going on, so is there a simple way? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try and manipulate the UI directly in code, why not just modify the itmes you're databinding to the list and add a property to indicate if it's the last one. YOu can then use this property in the DataTemplate to control how it should be displayed.

Comment: Okay, got it. This worked! But in the end it was also a binding issue. My ListBox just didn't had enough time to be filled. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try accessing the `ListBoxItem` via `ItemContainerGenerator`?

```
((ListBoxItem)myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(myListBox.Items.Count-1)).Margin = new Thickness(42, 0, 0, 0);
```

This should work. Otherwise something is wrong with your binding.

Comment: Tried that, still NullReferenceException... myListBox.Items is null so myListBox.Items.Count-1 won't give me any results. I will check for binding issues, thanks!

Comment: I had a NullReferenceException with your code with Items!=null - thought it was this you were hitting. Good hunt :)